# How do I check if 3 letters in a string are equal to '0-0' in Python?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a program in python in which the computer reads out Chess Notation, this is the code I have written which translates Chess Notation into words which a human would say:

```
def say(chess_line):
line_of_chess = ""
for i in chess_line:
    if i == "x":
        i = " Takes "
    if i == "N":
        i = " Knight "
    if i == "B":
        i = " Bishop "
    if i == "R":
        i = " Rook "
    if i == "Q":
        i = " Queen "
    if i == "K":
        i = " King "
    line_of_chess += i
```

In Chess Notation, in order to signal to castle, one must write '0-0' (or '0-0-0' for long castling). How do I change the string "0-0" to "Castles", and "0-0-0" to "Castles queenside"?

Comment: I assume you're doing this character by character there.  When there's a castling, usually that will be the only thing on that line, right?  So just do "if chess_line=='O-O':` or "if chess_line=="O-O-O":`.

Comment: You presumably also need to handle "+" for check, and "!" for good move, and "?" for questionable move.

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
if i == "O-O":
    i = " Castles "
```

Another option that might be more Pythonic would be to put all the chess moves in a dictionary that maps the chess notation to human notation. Then you just have to look up the chess notation in the dictionary, instead of doing all the `if` statements.

```
chess_to_human = {
    "x": "Takes",
    "N": "Knight",
    "B": "Bishop",
    "R": "Rook",
    "Q": "Queen",
    "K": "King",
    "O-O": "Castles"
}

for i in chess_line:
    print(chess_2_human[i])
```

Comment: First, it's a letter O, not a number 0.  Second, his "i" in that loop is character by character.  You can't store O-O in a single character.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts, I changed it from number 0 to letter O. I initially though the OP was looping through lines of chess moves.

Comment: Yes, but he is looping through the line character by character.  You need to check the whole LINE for that value.